# Chosen-select not updating after onchange

Tags: jquery

I've been trying to work through other peoples comments about using $("#sub-cats").trigger("chosen:updated"); for my .change function and for the life of me I can't get my chosen-select to update after the script empty's the options and appends a new one.

The original select updates with the new options each time as expected, it seems to just be due to the updating of the chosen-select.

```
<script>
                $("#top-category").change(function(){
                  var id = $(this).find("option:selected").attr("id");

                  switch (id){
                    case "career":
$('#sub-cats')
.find('option')
.remove()
.end()
.append('<option value="whatever">text</option>')
.val('whatever')
;


                      break;
                    case "interview":
$('#sub-cats')
.find('option')
.remove()
.end()
.append('<option value="whatever">another text</option>')
.val('whatever')
;                        
                      break;
                    case "all":

                      break;
                  }
                });

            </script>
```

UPDATE: Apologies, I may not have been all that clear above, my first select (#top-category) onchange alters the contents of #sub-cats by emptying all the options and adding in new ones. This process works perfectly except the selects also incorporate jquery chosen-select, the original select boxes update correctly but chosen-select doesn't pickup the change.

I have tried adding the .trigger("chosen:updated"); to each individual onchange action and also at the end of the .change statement with no affect.

Comment: I didn't get what you want to do exactly do you want to change the first select after changing the second?

Comment: Apologies Kholy, my first select (#top-category) onchange alters the contents of #sub-cats by emptying all the options and adding in new ones. This process works perfectly except the selects also incorporate jquery chosen-select , the original select boxes update correctly but chosen-select doesn't pickup the change.

I have tried adding the .trigger("chosen:updated"); to each individual onchange action and also at the end of the .change statement with no affect.